# React router functional component redirect on event

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a functional component with a react-router.
Working fine when using `<Link ... />` but I want to redirect on some event.
The problem is that `props.history` is undefined.

```
function App(props) {
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(props.history);
    //props.history.push("/about");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link> <br />
        <button onClick={onClick}>
          <b>onclick redirect</b>
        </button>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-demo-o6s89

How can I redirect programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you `App` component in `withRouter` HOC and move `BrowserRouter` to `AppContainer` component.
This should work.

```
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App(props) {
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(props.history);
    props.history.push("/about");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/about">About</Link> <br />
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        <b>onclick redirect</b>
      </button>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
  );
}

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

const AppContainer = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppWithRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, what happens when it comes to sub-component? history should be passed manually to each subcomponent? if so, that's crazy... thanks

Comment: No...wrap sub components in withRouter HOC. Or use `useHistory` hook if you are using the latest version of react-router-dom. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `this.props.history` is `undefined` is because you can only acces this prop in a route that is set. The prop is passed to all the routes. If what you want is redirecting the user from the app component, then you should use the `Link` component.

[image: Edit react-router-demo]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import About from "./components/About";

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Link path="/about" to="about">About</Link> 
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```
import React from "react";

const About = props => {
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(props);
    props.history.push("/about");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        <b>onclick redirect</b>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```